# When can Wookie Loyalty be applied?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

Wookiee Loyalty: Exhaust this card while you or an adjacent friendly figure is defending to apply +1 Block to the defense results.

An issue came up with in our recent game about the timing of using this ability. Do you need to declare it and exhaust it before the dice are rolled? Or can you wait to see the results of the dice roll and then choose to use it?

Answer (score 2):

From the wording of the card, it suggests you can use it at any point during the defence i.e. after the dice results have been seen.

It seems a bit risky/useless to insist it happens before the dice roll. It would certainly be more fun to see the results first.